# Should I duplicate my Azure Web Job instance for increase flexibility?

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-webjobs

I got a web job that has multiple routines, and for execute a specific routine, the routine's name is passed as job's argument. All these routines must be executed, and there's a dependency between them (a routine's input might be other routine's output); so for orchestrate this, I'm planning to use a **Logic App** which actually would call the same web job, but passing different parameters.

By doing all above, I'd have a single web job instance, and I'd control job flow by using a Logic App. **But here's come my concern...** let's suppose I only want to execute a specific routine *(which is standalone, it doesn't have a dependency to another routine)* because it failed *(or maybe I want to debug it)*, so I have to go the my Web Jobs portal in Azure, and copy the job's web hook url, set the job parameters as query parameters for call the routine desired, and then call it through a HTTP client. But the problem that I see with this is that isn't that friendly: I have to do all these stuffs for call a specific job's routine.

To resolve my above concern I was planning to duplicate the job instance (the duplication term used here it's not for scaling, it's for flexibility), and hardcode the routine's name into each job duplication. The only pros that I see is run a specific routine by just going directly to its respective job instance, and click in "Run" button (Azure Portal). But also, the cons that I see here is that I'm duplicating the same source code (the same binaries), but just passing a different parameter (in this case routine's name), so in term of maintainability, it's a pain because if something changes in the job source code, I have to redeploy "routines count" times for consistency (all jobs are running under the same source code).

So should I sacrifice **code maintainability** (redeploy many times the same source code, and play with job parameters) for get a friendly way for job execution, or not? I'd like to hear your opinion! If there's more information needed, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

If you can choose how the job is triggered, I would take a look at using [Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#service-bus-trigger-configuration-version-3x) instead of Logic Apps to handle the chaining. You can use different queues within the same bus to handle calling different part of your Web Job and the parameters you want to pass can be done within the message instead of http parameters. The primary advantage here is that it includes retry logic. If a job fails, the message returns to the queue to be run again. You can configure it to retry a specific number of times (default is 10) before the message is moved to a dead letter queue. If you want to do some control flow outside of the Web Job you can keep the Logic App in play: Web Job => Logic App => Service Bus => back to Web Job.

If you only want one copy of the service running at a time, then you do need to stick with Web Jobs, but you may want to look at [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#compare-functions-and-webjobs) instead. They are designed to do these sorts of small jobs and can be chained together internally, with Logic Apps or with Service Bus. It is built on top of the Web Jobs SDK, so in most cases the code changes are minimal. I can't say for sure as I haven't seen your code, but more than likely you would split each job into separate function instead of using parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Especially for the comparison between an Azure Function and an Azure Web Job. Giving you more info: my tasks are long ones, it could take 1-4 hours for accomplish all of them; that's why I was planning in Azure Web Jobs in first instance, because I see Azure Functions fit perfect in short running tasks (correct me if I'm wrong, please). So the main idea was scheduling these long running jobs by using a Logic App.

Comment: Functions on the consumption plan do have a hard limit of 10 minutes. Attached to a paid plan, they act more like webjobs and can run as long as you want them to. They were intended for short jobs, but I know of customers that prefer them for their long running tasks as well- it is up to you.

Comment: A long run time does exclude Service Bus from handling your retries- after a max of 5 minutes it will assume the job failed. A storage queue request can be configured to hold the message for up to 5 days before releasing it, so you could set it to, say, 3 hours and get a similar effect.